# How to match nearly equal string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to filter items from `array` based on matching `string` but `string` is not completely equal. That contains few keywords of it. Example, I want to match `PGVF.NonSubmit.Action` with `NonSubmit` etc. This code is not working and matching complete `string`.

This is my code

```
for (let i = 0; i < appNames.length; i++)
{
   var strToMatch=appNames[i]
   let obj=products.filter(x=>strToMatch.includes(x.Name))
}
```

Where `obj` should get multiple matching records. I need to do this from loop only as I have to perform other operations in loop. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using below code

```
const matches = Object.values(products).filter(s =>s.Name.toString().includes(strToMatch));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `match()` function

Matching "**NonSubmit**" in "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"

```
console.log("PGVF.NonSubmit.Action".match("NonSubmit"))

>>>[ 'NonSubmit', index: 5, input: 'PGVF.NonSubmit.Action', groups: undefined ]
```

Matching "**NoSubmit**" in in "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"

```
console.log("PGVF.NonSubmit.Action".match("NoSubmit"))

>>>null
```